# Jquery time interval between more functions

Tags: jquery, slider, setinterval

I want to make a slider.

I have 5 functions and i want to run the first function, after 5 seconds the second one, after 5 second the third one and so on.

When the 5th function runs, wait 5 seconds and run the first one again and the cycle repeat;

I've tried to use SetInterval,but i don't know what values to write there to match what i've just said.

setInterval(img1,5000);

setInterval(img2,3000);

setInterval(img3,4000);

setInterval(img4,9000);

setInterval(img5,9000);

Anybody had the same problem?

Comment: +1 for trying to create a slider on ur own!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your functions in an array, you can use a for loop to access them. Try running this in the console. You'll see it executes each function, then starts the loop process again.

This way if you add any more functions like `img6`,`img7`, and so on, you won't have to refactor which one starts the Timeout loop again.

```
var img1 = function() { console.log('1'); }
var img2 = function() { console.log('2'); }
var img3 = function() { console.log('3'); }
var img4 = function() { console.log('4'); }
var img5 = function() { console.log('5'); }
var functions = [img1,img2,img3,img4,img5];

var loop = function() { 
    for(var i=0; i < functions.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                functions[i]();
            }, 5000 * i);
        })(i);
    }
setTimeout(loop,(5000*(functions.length)));
}
loop();
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, but when i activate manually function img3 for example(by clicking a button of slider) the loop will continue from the previous point she left, not from actual point.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval repeats a given function on a timer given a time. I don't think that's what you are looking for. I think you are looking for setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function1, 5000); // execute function1 after 5000 milliseconds
```

then you should define function1 like so:

```
function function1() {
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(function2, 5000);
}
```

and so on for all 5 functions.

then you can have function5 call function1 to restart the chain. More info can be found [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something along these lines:

```
var fnOrig = [
     function() {
         // do first action
     },
     function() {
         // do second action
     }
     // keep defining functions
 ],
 fnCopy = fnOrig.slice(0);

 setTimeout(function() {
     if (!fnCopy.length) 
         fnCopy = fnOrig.slice(0);
     fnCopy.pop()();
 }, 5000);
```